# Do I need a/the in this situation?

Tags: articles

Suppose I want to write:

> We want everybody to contribute with minimum barrier to entry.

Grammarly suggests I need to either say `a minimum` or `the minimum`. I find that odd but Grammarly always nags me about this and I got a bit unsure.

Comment: Can you also explain what you are trying to say with your original example sentence? I might be helpful. I personally don't immediately understand what you're trying to say, though I can guess. Please see [Details, Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/36187) and the [Contributor's Guide (Asking)](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4785/36187) for tips and examples.

Comment: have you tried to use minimal?

Comment: I'd second @lopushen's minimal suggestion. The sentence as written doesn't really make sense to me.

Comment: Alternatively, did you perhaps mean "We want everybody to contribute _to_ a minimal barrier to entry" ? While you can say "contribute with", it would be typically used like "The paint company contributed with a donation of 50 liters of paint". Or is there a missing comma? "We want everybody to contribute, with minimal barrier to entry."?

Comment: @Msalters What I wanted to say was, "We want everybody to contribute, and while everybody is contributing they should face minimal barrier that would make it difficult for them to contribute" (I hope this makes sense)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrasing of the sentence could be improved. You can also use the plural *barriers* in order to avoid having to choose between *a* or *the* (if neither sounds right to you).

Using the plural also makes sense if there really isn't just one barrier—or you don't know how many there will be ahead of time. Perhaps there are multiple entry criteria.

> We want to minimize entry barriers to anybody's contribution.

Comment: The "barriers" refer to the *people,* not to the *contributions* themselves. I think "We want to minimize entry barriers to anybody who contributes"  (or "to anyone who wishes to contribute") would be better.

Answer (score 1):

In this sentence you would need a/the

> We want everyone to contribute with **a** minimum barrier to enter

meaning you want all the personal to contribute a certain amount of a certain object to enter

> We want everyone to contribute with **the** minimum barrier to enter

meaning pretty much the same, you wish people to contribute the minimum amount to enter. The sentence doesn't really work without a/the.